# Convexity of a function defined on $W^{1,p}(]0,r[)$

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality, convexity-inequality

Consider the continuous, non-decreasing function $$\beta:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$ where $\beta(0)=0.$

Define $$g(s)=\int_0^s \beta(u)du,$$ where $s$ is a positive constant.

Let now $A=\{w \in W^{1,p}(]0,r[), w(0)=0, w(r)=q \},$

where $r$, $q>0.$

Define $$J:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ as $$J(w)=\int_0^r g(w(t))dt, ~~ \mbox{for all}~ w \in A.$$

My question is, how to prove that $J$ is a convex function? I really tried but with no result.

My trial:

For $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $w_1$, $w_2$ $\in A$, we have

$$J(\lambda w_1+(1-\lambda)w_2)=\int_0^r g(\lambda w_1(t)+(1-\lambda)w_2(t))dt,$$

with $$g(\lambda w_1(t)+(1-\lambda)w_2(t))=\int_0^{\lambda w_1(t)+(1-\lambda)w_2(t)}\beta(u)du,$$ and stuck here.

I need please a continuation to my answer, or a logical answer. Many thanks.

Comment: You need to prove that $g$ is convex.

Comment: see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Function_is_Convex_iff_Derivative_is_Increasing